# I forgot the last few digits of the password to my Bitcoin Core wallet. How can I recover it?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-recovery, passphrase, recover-private-key, lost-wallet

As of 2013, I created a Bitcoin Core wallet and transferred 2.968638 BTC into the wallet from another wallet. At that time, I was saving money to buy bitcoins. Unluckily, I set the password to be encrypted for, of course, more security. Then, in 2018 when BTC pumped, when I tried to open the wallet to transfer the BTC to my Binance account, I forgot the last four digits of my password.

So I tried to force my mind to remember. I tried many passwords but nothing helped. I don’t know the last four digits.

I don't know how to get the full password. I have been worried since 2018, and I talked to many people, but they are asking for my wallet backup file. However, I can't give them my backup file; it's too risky. The funds are still in the wallet, and seeing the funds in the wallet that I can't access is working like chili in my nose.

If anyone knows how to fix this problem, please let me know.

Comment: Questions seeking help for restoring user accounts or other matters concerning your customer relationship with a company should be directed at the respective customer service. Please understand that we have no insights into such matters and therefore consider them as off-topic.